# fleqn odd behaviour with long formulas

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

I have a document containing several formulas of different lengths that I need to be aligned on the left. To achieve that I used the `fleqn` option in `\documentclass`. It works as expected with most of the formulas, but the longest ones are not indented, as if they weren't written on a line apart:

[image: MWE image]

How can I fix that without breaking my formula in more lines?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Lorem ipsum sit amet}
Short formula: aligned as wanted (the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog)
\[\begin{split}
    V_{x}           & = \frac{V_{0} - \sum_{m}^{n}Sp + \sum_{m}^{n}Pr} {q^{(n-m)}} = \\
                    & = 10000
\end{split}\]

Longer formula: aligned as wanted (the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog)
\[\begin{split}
    \sum_{x}^{y}Sp & = \bigg(1000\frac{q^a-1}{r}q^{b}
                        + 2000\frac{q^{c}-1}{r}q^d\bigg)
                        + \bigg(3000\frac{q^e-1}{r}q
                        + 4000\bigg) = \\
                    & = 5000
\end{split}\]

Even longer formula: oddly aligned (the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog)
\[\begin{split}
    \sum_{x}^{y}Pr & = \bigg(100000\frac{q^a-1}{r}q^{b}
                        + 200000\frac{q^{c}-1}{r}q^d\bigg)
                        + \bigg(300000\frac{q^e-1}{r}q
                        + 400000\bigg) = \\
                    & = 500000
\end{split}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No odd behavior. The formula doesn't fit the line and LaTeX does its best to accommodate it.

Split the overlong line.

Note. Use `\biggl` and `\biggr`, not the unadorned `\bigg`. Also it's not customary to repeat the equals sign (but your typographic tradition might mandate it; try and avoid it, it's unnecessary).

```latex
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Lorem ipsum sit amet}
Short formula: aligned as wanted (the quick brown fox jumps over the 
lazy dog and the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog)
\[\begin{split}
    V_{x}           & = \frac{V_{0} - \sum_{m}^{n}Sp + \sum_{m}^{n}Pr} {q^{(n-m)}} \\
                    & = 10000
\end{split}\]

Longer formula: aligned as wanted (the quick brown fox jumps over the 
lazy dog and the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog)
\[\begin{split}
    \sum_{x}^{y}Sp & = \biggl(1000\frac{q^a-1}{r}q^{b}
                        + 2000\frac{q^{c}-1}{r}q^d\biggr)
                        + \biggl(3000\frac{q^e-1}{r}q
                        + 4000\biggr)\\
                    & = 5000
\end{split}\]

Even longer formula: oddly aligned (the quick brown fox jumps over the 
lazy dog and the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog)
\[\begin{split}
    \sum_{x}^{y}Pr & = \biggl(100000\frac{q^a-1}{r}q^{b}
                        + 200000\frac{q^{c}-1}{r}q^d\biggr) \\
                  &\qquad+ \biggl(300000\frac{q^e-1}{r}q
                        + 400000\biggr) \\
                    & = 500000
\end{split}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I supposed it was because of something like LaTeX's accomodating system. I was wondering whether there is a way to suggest it a way to do that in another way, such as slightly reducing the space between the signs - I'd really prefer not to split the line.

Comment: @Ntakwetet Reducing the space could perhaps help in some situations. With the standard text width, the equation you have doesn't fit no matter what.